# Border in unordered list doesn't fit the whole width of the div

Tags: html, css, border, html-lists

I'm making a vertical unordered block list (inside a div), in which I have a border under each li. But somehow the borders don't fit the whole width of the div. I guess the ul has to exactly fit in the div in order to do this, but I don't know how.

This is screen shot of the div and the ul in it:

[image: list in the div]

And this is the CSS code I'm using:

```
.stats-list li{
    zoom:  1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
    border-spacing:30px;
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    height:40px;
}
.stats-list ul{
    list-style-type:none;

}
```

I've never come across this problem before. Does anyone have any solution? Thanks.

UPDATE (HTML code):

```
<div class="checkin-stats-right">
        <ul class="stats-list">
            <li>bla blaaa</li>
            <li>blaaaa</li>       
            <li>blaaaaaa</li>  
        </ul>

</div>
```

Another update (CSS code of the parent div):

```
.checkin-stats-right{
    background-color: #cfcfcf;
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-right: auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:25px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `UL` element usually has a `padding-left` set to a certain amount of pixels. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .stats-list li {
                zoom:  1;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
                border-spacing:30px;
                display:block;
                text-align:left;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                color:#ffffff;
                height:40px;
            }

            ul.stats-list {
                list-style-type:none;
                padding-left: 0;
            }

            .checkin-stats-right {
                background-color: #cfcfcf;
                width: 320px;
                height: 180px;
                margin-right: auto;
                float:left;
                margin-left:25px;
                margin-top:25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="checkin-stats-right">
            <ul class="stats-list">
                <li>bla blaaa</li>
                <li>blaaaa</li>       
                <li>blaaaaaa</li>  
            </ul>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but that doesn't work either. I will update my question with the CSS code of the parent div, maybe that helps.

Comment: Updated my answer with complete code. Let me know if this works. Your code has some other issues I fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. the problem was stats-list ul{} which had to be ul.stats-list{} :)

Comment: That incombination with the `padding-left` property on the `UL` element :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.stats-list ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Also note that "ul.stats-list" in your HTML doesn't match ".stats-list ul"

Comment: padding left doesn't solve the problem in this case. And I don't understand what you mean by that? What should I do to match that and what am I doing wrong? Thanks.